# FIlter Array and get count of filtered array

Tags: javascript

I want to filter following two arrays and get the count of `"isimplemented: 'Yes'"` elements:

```
const arr1 = [{ProjectName: "IT", Department: "Software"}]
const arr2 = [{Name: "IT", isimplemented: "Yes"}]
```

I tried the following method to do the same but not getting desired result. How I can do it in JavaScript

```
((arr1.map(data => data.ProjectName)).filter(arr1.map(data => data.ProjectName) === arr2.map(data => data.Name) && isimplemented === "Yes")).length
```

Comment: Your "array"'s syntax is invalid - arrays do not have key-value pairs when being declared, only values

Comment: Do you mean an array object? As @CertainPerformance Pointed that **arrays do not have key-value pairs** while the objects does

Comment: Yes I mean array object. How could I do that?

Comment: please add more data and the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could teka a `Set` for the implemented projects and then count the occurences of the project who are implemented.

```js
const
    arr1 = [{ ProjectName: "IT", Department: "Software" }],
    arr2 = [{ Name: "IT", isimplemented: "Yes" }],
    implemented = arr2.reduce((s, { Name, isimplemented }) => isimplemented === 'Yes' ? s.add(Name) : s, new Set),
    count = arr1.reduce((c, { ProjectName }) => c + implemented.has(ProjectName), 0);

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First merge the different arrays to create one single array
2. Create a variable which will keep track of your count
3. use forEach to iterate over the elements in the array, increment the count for every array-object having property isImplemented: 'Yes'

```js
 const arr1 = [{ProjectName: "IT", Department: "Software"}]
 const arr2 = [{Name: "IT", isimplemented: "Yes"}]  
 const newArr = [...arr1, ...arr2] 
 let count = 0
 newArr.forEach(element => {
        if (element.isimplemented === 'Yes') {
            count++ 
        }
    })

console.log(count)
```